# Finding a terminating character for winsocks that can't possibly exist in files

Tags: windows, file, winsock2

I am using winsocks for a TCP client/server, it sends const char*,
issue is, calling send(clientsocket, sendBuffer, strlen(sendBuffer)+1, 0) once
sends each character in char sendBuffer[512] individually, and is received char by char. Ideally I would like to have all 512 elements received "at once", but can live without it if that's not possible.

So I need to find a terminating character, since my goal is to send files, I need a char that *can't* be found in a file. This is the code I use to serialize the file

```
char* read_file(string path, int& len)
{
    std::ifstream infile(path);

    infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
    size_t length = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);
    len = length;
    char* buffer = new char[len]();

    infile.read(buffer, length);
    return buffer;
}

string load_to_buffer()
{
    char* img;
    int ln;
    img = read_file("C:\\Users\\they\\Documents\\sock.txt", ln);
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <= ln; i++){
        s += *(img + i);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Code to send:

```
strcpy(SenderBuffer, s.c_str());
            resend_packet:
                iSend = send(TCPClientSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In a binary file, any value can occur. It is also extremely dangerous to equate bytes with characters...

Comment: How do you recommend I terminate the stream, a sequential code like "end"? that could appear in a text file though,
if not is there a way to set the socket to send the whole array "at once"?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem for an explanation.

A common pattern is just to close the stream when you have no more data to send.
If you know how much data that you wish to send, then transmit the length as a header, before the rest of the data. Basically, separate metadata from the data.

Comment: thank you, by the way why is it dangerous to equate bytes to characters if I'm using single byte chars?

Comment: Can you guarantee the bytes correspond?
In the C and C++ worlds, strings used to be null terminated arrays of bytes.
In the world of Unicode, which we live in, individual characters may have a variable number of bytes per character, depending on the character.
If you mean your data to be an array of bytes, then you should declare it as such.
Some compilers will prefer "wide" characters over byte size ones.